Problem installing R package called 'bspm' on Ubuntu 24.04
I recently I updated my Ubuntu to 24.04. Now when I open RStudio I have this error message:

I can't install the bspm package. I already tried the recommendation in this post, but it didn't work. I also tried to do this text Finally I read about the problem and found this information, but neither of them worked.
Apparently the problem is that the repository has not yet created a URL for noble.



Maybe a solution
Maybe a solution, but it didn't work either.
When I run install.packages("bspm") from inside an R session I get this:
Error en loadNamespace(x): no hay paquete llamado 'bspm' 
Calls: loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart Ejecución interrumpida 
Warning in install.packages: installation of package 'bspm' had non-zero exit status. 
The downloaded source packages are in '/tmp/Rtmp04ur7K/downloaded_packages'


Download this .deb package (built for 22.04) from Launchpad and install it manually. Did that work?

Also try this https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/. It has a section about installing bspm

Please tell us what you did. Don't tell us you followed some link, show the exact commands you ran. And please  don't post images of text. Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the formatting tools to format it as code. What happens if you run install.packages("bspm") from inside an R seesion?

@ArchismanPanigrahi Thank you very much, It worked! I downloaded the .deb package built for 22.04

The solution is to download the .deb package for 22.04 from Launchpad and install it manually.
